# What's the difference between $ \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $ 4\mathbb{Z} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

Can someone please explain the difference between $ \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} $ and $ 4\mathbb{Z} $?

From my understanding (please correct where I'm wrong): the group $4\mathbb{Z}$ has only four elements, $\{0,1,2,3\}$, and the group $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ also has the same four elements.

So, are they really so different?

Comment: $4\mathbb Z=\{\dots,-12,-8,-4,0,4,8,12,\dots\}$.

Comment: @ron $4\Bbb Z$ is the [coset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset) $\{4k:k\in \Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: One is finite the other is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $4\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, and $\Bbb{Z/4Z}$ is the quotient group we get when we divide $\Bbb Z$ by $4\Bbb Z$.

The former is infinite and contains all the multiples of $4$ in $\Bbb Z$, the latter is finite and has four elements.

Answer (score 1):

Even more than just $4\mathbb{Z}$ having infinite order and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ having order $4,$ $4\mathbb{Z}$ (which is the set of all integer multiples of $4$ under addition) is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is the cyclic group of order $4.$

So they are indeed very different groups.